# How to grant the privilege of creating a session to a user or role in PostgreSQL?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-permissions

I am migrating this Oracle command to PostgreSQL:

```
GRANT CREATE SESSION  TO user;
```

Please suggest to me how I can migrate the above command.

Answer (score 0):

There are three steps:

1. It has to be a login role

   ```
   ALTER ROLE theuser LOGIN;
   ```
2. There has to be an entry in `pg_hba.conf` that matches the incoming connection by that user.
3. The user has to have the `CONNECT` privilege on the database.

Comment: CREATE USER username  IDENTIFIED BY  password;
 GRANT CREATE SESSION  TO username;

Comment: This is my oracle script.There is no database here to grant connect privilege in postgresql

Comment: Different software works differently. Just because Oracle doesn't have database permissions (you don't need them in that architecture) doesn't mean it is the same in PostgreSQL. You cannot translate your script line by line. I showed you the hurdles you have to overcome to connect to PostgreSQL. The next one would be authentication.

Comment: alter ROLE username  WITH LOGIN;
GRANT CONNECT
ON DATABASE database_name 
TO user_name;

Comment: do we have any grant for creating the table ,SEQUENCE,view ?

Comment: Yes, we do. It is all described under `GRANT` in the documentation.